# C++ Win32: fast word processing-style text rendering under Windows 7

Tags: c++, windows-7, richtext, wordprocessingml

At user request, my (for now C#) application reads big chunks of rich text (for now, in .NET FlowDocument XAML format) from a SQL Server database, and displays it.

I use a C# RichTextBox for that, it works but the whole thing is much too slow (the whole application is not very responsive). I want to remake everything in native C++.

What is the best way to get fast rich text rendering in Windows 7?

I would welcome suggestions

1) on the text API to use (Direct2D/DirectWrite or GDI or something else? use glyphs or higher level functions?),

2) also on how to store the rich text in memory to accomodate scrolling up and down the flow of text, insertion in the middle of the text etc.

Thanks.